# How do I convert time series data to a NN input vector?

Tags: python, vector, tensorflow, time-series, tflearn

For example, I have `csv` time series data for various stocks and I would like to convert the data into vectors which would be feed-able into a neural network.

I'm not sure if this would be of any relevance but ultimately, I would want to predict future stock price based on various current fundamental metrics - TDebt, IntAssets, TAssets, and EBITDA. Then, I compare PriceToday and Price+1Yr. If the PriceDiff is positive, data is labeled Correct, if Negative, data is labeled Incorrect.

Date,Ticker, TDebt , IntAssets , TAssets , EBITDA , PriceToday , Price+1Yr , PriceDiff , Label 
1/1/10,AAPL,6.73,3.05,41.16,11.06,179.26,219.26,22.31,Correct
1/1/10,GOOGL,3.19,12.54,24.08,2.63,1135.97,1115.97,-1.76,Incorrect
1/1/10,MSFT,4.32,15.74,35.84,7.43,90.1,94.1,4.44,Correct
1/1/10,AMZN,0.52,0.24,18.5,7.55,1293.32,1044.32,-19.25,Incorrect
1/1/10,FB,3.32,7.79,15.05,0.63,179.8,156.8,-12.79,Incorrect
1/1/10,BABA,13.61,18.02,122.56,25.31,184.4,205.4,11.39,Correct
1/1/10,JNJ,5.18,2.54,39.44,8.06,146.92,185.92,26.55,Correct
1/1/10,XOM,2.23,-2.17,94.32,14.52,87.43,48.43,-44.61,Incorrect
1/1/11,AAPL,7.27,3.35,42.9,12.04,219.26,230.26,5.02,Correct
1/1/11,GOOGL,4.01,12.8,24.87,2.34,1115.97,1135.97,1.79,Correct
1/1/11,MSFT,5.4,14.04,33.84,5.04,94.1,88.1,-6.38,Incorrect
1/1/11,AMZN,0.59,0.31,19.04,9.31,1044.32,1396.32,33.71,Correct
1/1/11,FB,2.8,9.08,16.04,0.74,156.8,151.8,-3.19,Incorrect
1/1/11,BABA,12.68,19.03,124.05,24.03,205.4,216.4,5.36,Correct
1/1/11,JNJ,6.01,2.7,37.04,10.02,185.92,174.92,-5.92,Incorrect
1/1/11,XOM,2.8,-2.9,93.1,13.23,48.43,78.43,61.95,Correct
1/1/12,AAPL,7.18,-4.88,67.78,26.03,230.26,209.26,-9.12,Incorrect
1/1/12,GOOGL,1.05,0.47,102.09,11.29,1135.97,1145.97,0.88,Correct
1/1/12,MSFT,6.45,-5.68,59.01,21.42,88.1,58.1,-34.05,Incorrect
1/1/12,AMZN,6.23,1.59,19.44,6.91,1396.32,1276.32,-8.59,Incorrect
1/1/12,FB,6.08,-1.15,53.7,13.43,151.8,156.8,3.29,Correct
1/1/12,BABA,10.89,12.57,194.62,20.91,216.4,204.4,-5.55,Incorrect
1/1/12,JNJ,5.88,5.48,78.08,12.8,174.92,184.92,5.72,Correct
1/1/12,XOM,14.57,0.92,121.11,13.76,78.43,66.43,-15.3,Incorrect

Thank you for your help.

Comment: read it using pandas, then convert to whatever format you need using their conversions. Pandas stores data as numpy arrays so you're basically done then

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the code you would run to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As `@evamicur` is explaining, you should use pandas library to convert your date. 
I would do something like, but you should edit to your need:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Note, I would also change my label to either 0 or 1 instead of 'Correct' and 'Incorrect' for your NN.

```
df[' Label '] = df[' Label '].map({'Correct ': 1, 'Incorrect ': 0})
```

You should also get rid of all the spaces in your csv file.
Hope this help.